# Manga where a guy sent back in time by a dragon's power goes to magic school to try to keep his time from being destroyed

Tags: story-identification, manga

The protagonist is male sent back in time by a dragon's power.

He goes back to school for magic which is segregated into alpha class and beta class. He wants to change this as alpha class is the upper class society, and beta is the commoners. The alpha class receives better training, which is not shared with beta class.

"Abe/Arian" (protagonist's name starts with an "A") he meets the girl he fell in love with who was his superior when first entering school of magic. He then gets her, and another female who is a magic swordsman to join his group. Together they strive to get stronger and fight the calamities of the past that could destroy the present.

Abe, using his knowledge is able to control others' magic before its cast, will try to get stronger in this life to protect his love and the people of the world from the calamities to come.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is *A Returner's Magic Should Be Special*.

It starts off with a group of people fighting a dragon. They defeat it with Desir Arman, the main character, using his magic to stop the dragon's magic.  Afterwards he mentions that he was not fully trained or educated.  The first chapter ends with the dragon's body's remaining magic exploding, which ends up sending Desir into the past when he was taking the magic academy's entrance exam.

During the entrance exam he meets Ajest, a magic swordsman who was with the group that defeated the dragon in the future, and Romantica, the girl he had fell in love with in the future.  After the exam Desir, Romantica, and a boy named Pram form a party. Later Ajest also joins the party. At the school, they get sent into places called "Shadow Worlds". These worlds are past events that they then have to change to prevent a problem that had happened in the past.

Desir's objective is to prevent the calamities he experienced in the future from coming to pass by training his party to be stronger than they were to overcome the problems he knows they will face in the future.